# Balance is showing 00.0 when I imported the entries through a sql query in a Journal Entry. oddo10

Tags: sql, odoo-10, journal

What I have done is, I entered Opening Balances in journal Entry through a sql query mentioned below.

insert into account_move_line (move_id,journal_id, company_id, account_id, operating_unit_id, partner_id, name, currency_id, debit, credit, date_maturity) values(18467,79,1,3,10,11091,'TN',21,25538.71,0,'2018-03-31');

Both debit and Credit are showing. Balance being a compute field should reflect automatically but its showing 00.0. Any Idea where I have been wrong in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Import data using the traditional import mechanic, with a `.csv` file in a module `data` folder or charging your `.csv` file directly into screen.
2. After SQL insert, recomputing in a console the field needed, in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089393/how-to-recompute-stored-functional-field-values-in-odoo) you can see how to do that.

I hope this answer can be helful for you.

Comment: The thing did was that I Entered one Entry Manually and then Compared the table using PGAdmin and found few values missing. There after the balance was displaying.