# how to override on odoo methode?

Tags: python, inheritance, orm, odoo

assume there is an model like that

```
class HolidaysType(models.Model):

_name = "hr.holidays.status"
_description = "Leave Type"
```

have a method like

```
api.one
@api.depends('b')
def _compute_amount(self):
    a = b
    m = n
    h = f
    pass
```

and i need to add an inhertance model as:

```
class modelname(models.Model):
_inherit = 'hr.holidays.status'
```

then i need to make c = x+z and a = b+c in _compute_amount method

how can i do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `_compute_amount` method and add your code.

```
class modelname(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr.holidays.status'

    @api.one
    @api.depends('b')
    def _compute_amount(self):
        super(modelname, self)._compute_amount()
        c = x+z
        a = b+c
```

Create a new record to check if the values are correctly computed.

You can [recompute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089393/how-to-recompute-stored-functional-field-values-in-odoo) stored functional field values.

Comment: what is the differance between your answer and if i write super in return like return super(modelname, self)._compute_amount()

Comment: The compute method has to assign the field on all records of the invoked recordset. The return value should be `None`. And please if you do not mind, What do you expect when returning that value?