# how to run odoo combuted field on all records?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10, computed-field

hello everyone i haved been added an filed called employee_id, it gets the record id as the employee id computed field,
it worked well when any of depending fields change
but i need to run the function on all old date not while creating a new employee or i change the dependens

here is the method

```
@api.one
@api.depends('name')
def _compute_employee_id(self):
    for rec in self:
        rec.employee_id = rec.id
    pass

employee_id = fields.Char('Employee ID',compute='_compute_employee_id',store=True)
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: The `employee_id` depends only on `name` field. note that `@api.one` is not needed.

Comment: thanks dear, i know that and said that it work well while dependens change, i need to know how to make it work in bervious records

Comment: I just misunderstood your question.Please can you tell me what you mean by `bervious`?

Comment: the existed records before adding the method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recompute stored functional field values in Odoo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089393/how-to-recompute-stored-functional-field-values-in-odoo)

Comment: I have the same problem.How did you solved?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this right inside Odoo, no need to touch the server.

Enable the developer mode first, then go to `Settings` - `Technical` - `Actions` - `Server Actions`.

Create a new record, give it a name and select the model of your code, the `Action To Do` needs to be `Execute Python Code` with below code in the code field.

```
for record in records:
    record._compute_employee_id()
```

Save and click `Create Contextual Action`, refresh page, go to your module with list view opened, select all, click action, select the action you just created. When it is done, you can go back to server actions and delete the record.