# cannot get ID from partner_id.id in Odoo v11

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11, odoo-12

I got some issues on getting id from rest.partner in Odoo. I added compute field in stock.move.line called irLot. below is code sample.

```
class StockMoveLine(models.Model):
_inherit = 'stock.move.line'

irLot = fields.Char(string="Internal Reference", compute='_compute_ir')


def _compute_generate_lot(self):
    
    partner_id = self.picking_id.partner_id.id
    partner_obj = self.env['res.partner']
    obj = partner_obj.search([('id','=',partner_id)])
    
    for rec in obj:
        internal_ref = rec.ref
         
    self.irLot = internal_ref
```

so my problem is when I assign to partner_id variable. there is no value is coming out even though i assigned self.picking_id.partner_id.id. there is always showing False. so I assigned id directly and it works as below.

```
 partner_obj = self.env['res.partner']
 obj = partner_obj.search([('id','=','112')])
```

What did I do wrong?
quite noob on odoo please suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`irLot` depends on the value of `picking_id`, you need to specify it using `api.depends()` decorator.

> If it uses the values of other fields, it should specify those fields using `depends()`

You can refer to the [Computed fields](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/orm.html#computed-fields) documentation.

The default `picking_id` and `partner_id` are not mandatory, so check if they are set before trying to get their values. `self.picking_id.partner_id` when it is set is a recordset, you do not need to search using its `id`, you already have it as a record.

You can't set the value of a field on a recordset `self.irLot = internal_ref`, try to loop over `self` and set the value for each record.

```py
class StockMoveLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'stock.move.line'

    irLot = fields.Char(string="Internal Reference", compute='_compute_ir')

    @api.depends('picking_id')
    def _compute_generate_lot(self):
        for sml in  self:
            if sml.picking_id and sml.picking_id.partner_id:
                sml.irLot = sml.picking_id.partner_id.internal_ref
```

Comment: hi Kenly, thanks for answer. I tried but no luck. it is empty value. so how can i get id value from sml.picking_id.partner_id? i set up sml.picking_id.partner_id.id but show False only.

Comment: You need to [recompute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089393/how-to-recompute-stored-functional-field-values-in-odoo) the values for the already created records.

Comment: it should be self.recompute rgt? need to add end of compute function?

Comment: No, you need to execute ``recompute`` once. the compute method will trigger for new records when the ``picking_id`` change.

Comment: how can i exactly do ? can you give me example base on my code.

Comment: Start Odoo [shell](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/cmdline.html#shell) and use `self.env`.

Comment: Thanks and now I see, is there anyway to avoid recompute ?

Comment: The recompute is needed for stored computed fields, When you create a new record its value should be computed and set and if picking_id or partner_id or internal_ref are not set, Odoo should recompute it when one of those values change. In the example, above we only get a field value and set it to `irLot`, we could use a [related field](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#related-fields) instead.